# Is it possible to name a constraint based off of another table column T-SQL?

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, t-sql, asp.net-mvc-4

First, I'm working with asp.net 4.5 and this is T-SQL and MVC.

I can't find a clear answer online (so I'm guessing it's not possible). I wanted to know if you can set a constraint for a default value to be from a table's column. Such as:

Table A (Users):

```
ID | UserName |
---------------
1    Chuck
---
```

Table B:

```
ID  | List_Name |


[List_Name] NVARCHAR(128) NULL Default ([dbo].[Users] ([UserName]) + (' List')),
```

Or is it better to just add data-annotations to it in view and controller part?
If so, how would I do that in the controller by-chance?

I'm just diving into creating something and would like to know what a professional would do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, in Sql Server the default must be a constant expression - use an insert trigger if you want something more complex. Alternatively, when you insert the row, why not calculate the value for `List_Name` and use that in the insert?